# How to handle "read more or less" using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to load Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to apply "read more or less" in react component. The problem is that content in response is in html from or you can say rich text with all the

tags in it.
And from frontend i am handling this using

```
<div style={{ padding: 15 }}
     className="text-right single-content"
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />
```

But now as i am using  react library 'react-read-more-less' i have to write the component and have to load the content in this way

```
<ReadMoreAndLess ref={this.ReadMore}
                 className="read-more-content"
                 charLimit={250}
                 readMoreText="Read more"
                 readLessText="Read less">
  {post.content}
</ReadMoreAndLess>
```

But its not working properly its loading each tags associated with the content.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3zA1.png)

Thanks .

Comment: have you found any solution? I am getting the same issue. If found then please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your post content is HTML, you'll need to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser to avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: yeah, Thanks man!  i can use anyone from  "react-html-parser" or "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" . But the problem is i have to handle "read more or less". I need to apply read more or less on all the content to show or hide some percent. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks again.